# Footnotes and figures exceed margin

Tags: floats, packages, footnotes, margins, indentation

I must have messed something up with the packages that I load. Figures and footnotes exceed the margin of the text. Anybody knows why? See the MWE below which includes my full preamble. Some of that code in the header was intended to make sure that footnotes are not indented.

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
%\pdfminorversion=6
\usepackage[singlespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=0.8in,right=0.8in,top=0.8in,bottom=0.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage[]{blindtext}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage[affil-it, auth-sc]{authblk}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{table}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
%\usepackage[multiple]{footmisc}
\newcommand\fnsep{\textsuperscript{,}}
\renewcommand\Affilfont{\normalfont \itshape \small}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{ulem}
\renewcommand\Authsep{}
\renewcommand\Authand{}
\renewcommand\Authands{}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\newcommand{\RomanNumeralCaps}[1]{\MakeUppercase{\romannumeral #1}}
\makeatletter
\newlength{\fnBreite}
\renewcommand{\@makefntext}[1]{%
  \settowidth{\fnBreite}{\footnotesize\@thefnmark.i}
  \protect\footnotesize\upshape%
  \setlength{\@tempdima}{\columnwidth}\addtolength{\@tempdima}{-\fnBreite}%
  \makebox[\fnBreite][l]{\@thefnmark.\phantom{}}%
  \parbox[t]{\@tempdima}{\everypar{\hspace*{1em}}\hspace*{-1em}\upshape#1}}
\makeatother
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\appendixsection}{ m }{
    \renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{Appendix\ \csname the##1\endcsname\quad}
    \section{#1}
}
\makeatother
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{hypothesis}[theorem]{Hypothesis}
\definecolor{myauthor}{RGB}{0,120,0}
\usepackage[pdftex,unicode,colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=myauthor]{hyperref} 
\pagestyle{plain}

\title{A nice title \thanks{\noindent I thank Albert Einstein}}
\author[1]{Albus Dumbledore}
\affil[1]{Hogwarts}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}

\abstract{\noindent \lipsum[1]
\bigskip
\onehalfspacing
\setcounter{page}{0}
\newpage



\lipsum[2-4]
andginowbghworisb\footnote{adhbgwsoinf nABVDSVSFD ASGCQE ZHDA}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/pexels-pixabay-255419.jpg}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The figures and footnotes fit perfectly into the margins, what does not fit is your text. It still has the wider margins of the abstract. You need to conclude the abstract with `\end{abstract}` to get the correct margins for the text:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
  \lipsum[2]
\end{abstract}

\lipsum[2]
andginowbghworisb\footnote{adhbgwsoinf nABVDSVSFD ASGCQE ZHDA}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-duck}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]